# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes in virtual box on Windows 10 host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, freeze

I run Ubuntu 18.04 on virtual box on Windows 10 host. If I open a few windows, watch a youtube-video or do anything that is the least bit heavy ubuntu freezes and the windows task manager reports about 100% disk use. Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image: See this image of windows task manager!]

Comment: How much swap space have you allocated on the VM? If you run out of swap space a system will freeze. If your swap partition is too small you can use a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) instead.

Comment: How do I check the amount of memory allocated to swap?

Comment: Use the command `free -h`.

Comment: how much memory do you need for swap? or how do you determine that? @AFH

Comment: @qodeninja - Contrary to most advice, which recommends twice your RAM as swap size, I think this is nonsense, The more applications you run and the larger they are, the more memory you'll need, so the less RAM you have, the _more_ swap you'll need. The only way to estimate your swap requirement is to look at your application sizes. If you have the disc space, err by grossly overestimating the size, then run `free` periodically after the system has been running for some time and is fully loaded with all your applications; then you'll see how much of your swap is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the low RAM usage by VirtualBox, I think the virtual machine has too little RAM, which results in [thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19031902/1038828).

Try increasing the amount of RAM for the virtual machine.

I also noticed that your host RAM usage is quite high, so be careful with increasing the RAM allocation—too much RAM usage there may result in the *host* thrashing, which could freeze the host.  To prevent this, you need to close more programs on the host or install more RAM onto the host.

Comment: So I should give the virtual machine more RAM, but then again I shouldn't because it may result in host thrashing??

Comment: @JohanHagglevonNeubrücke: If that's the case, your computer (host) just might not have enough RAM to run two operating systems, which is why I suggested installing more RAM on the host.  You should strive to meet the system requirements of the host *plus* the system requirements of the VM.